# Reuse same single thread for same task again and again in wpf (c#) application without ThreadPool

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, mvvm

Creating An MVVM application where application wants to connect to server on a button click. After clicking the button, a thread will be created to connect to the server so that UI doesn't freeze and terminates(TIME OUT is 15 secs). Next time click on the button is creating again new thread to connect to server and terminates.

But first time I want to create a new thread and later I want to reuse that thread(not new) to do the "connect" task if application is not closed and user clicked on the same button.

Is that possible?

Below is the code:

```
Class ConnectViewModel:BaseViewModel
{
    public void ConnectToServer()
    {
        ConnectButtonEnable = false;
        ConnectingServerText = Properties.Resources.TryingToConnectServer;
        Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(connect));
        thread.Start(); 
        thread.Join();
    }

    public void connect()
    {
        bool bReturn = false;
        UInt32 iCommunicationServer;
        bReturn = NativeMethods.CommunicateServer(out iCommunicationServer);
        if (!bReturn || NativeMethods.ERROR_SUCCESS != iCommunicationServer)
        {
            ConnectingServerText = Properties.Resources.UnableToConnectToServer;                
        }
        else if (NativeMethods.ERROR_SUCCESS == iCommunicationServer)
        {
            ConnectingServerText = properties.Resources.SuccessfullyConnectedServer;
        }            
        ConnectButtonEnable = true;
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your thread.Join() essentially removes the asynchronicity you were hoping to create.

Comment: This question reeks of a lack of understanding, please specify better what you are trying to do and/or change your code example, because it really doesn't make sense.

Comment: @flindeberg I am clicking on "ConnectToServer" button on UI then ConnectToServer() function is executing. In that function I am first disabling the button by code "ConnectButtonEnable = false;" and starting new thread to execute function "connect". After successful communication or timeout period I am enabling the button again by "ConnectButtonEnable = true;" and joining the thread. The problem is next time when I click the "ConnectToServer" button it is again creating new thread. I don't want to start a new thread next time but I want to reuse the previous started thread.

Comment: @PareshModak Yes, that is clear, but why? Why are you using this approach? Have you tried `async`? Does it have to be a thread? There are better solutions than using an explicit thread (try to avoid starting threads manually in general).

Comment: @flindeberg I am learning c# and trying to reuse the previous created thread rather than again again starting new thread. There may be some better solutions i don't know, but can you please make me understand why my approach is not going to solve my issue? Also let me know some better solutions I will learn later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to how the question is phrased I would recommend you to read up on MVVM and async patterns, some examples:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn605875.aspx
- http://richnewman.wordpress.com/2012/12/03/tutorial-asynchronous-programming-async-and-await-for-beginners/

But in general, use `async`, don't manually create new threads when coding in a GUI-application. If the task shouldn't be callable whilst "running", do test and set via [`Interlocked.CompareExchange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.interlocked.compareexchange.aspx) and store away some state.

You use threads for parallel work, not for "waiting on the network".

Answer (score 0):

You can use the TPL to achieve this.

```
private Task previous = Task.FromResult(true);
public Task Foo()
{
    previous = previous.ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        DoStuff();
    });
    return previous;
}
```

By having the operation schedule each operation as the continuation of the previous operation, you ensure that each one doesn't start until the one that came before it finished, while still running all of them in background threads.

Answer (score 0):

Dont worry about creating and managing threads, just use `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` instead - its very efficient.

Comment: That doesn't help him solve his problem of preventing the operations from overlapping.